# Display URL image into a JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, url, jpanel

I'm trying to add an URL image into my `JPanel` on my Java GUI.
But when I run my program, then the `JPanel` is still empty:

```java
Image image = null;
try {

    URL url = new URL("http://www.mkyong.com/image/mypic.jpg");
    image = ImageIO.read(url);

} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
jPanel2 = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
jPanel2.add(label);
jPanel2.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Did you add the `JPanel` to something that could actually display it, or are you assuming the panel can magically show itself?

Comment: no i did not , but how i do that ?

Comment: [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

Comment: but i have already a frame , i added this panel into my gui , so i added a jpanel into my jframe

Comment: Then there is something else wrong with your code because it works fine me. It would also have been advantages to have provided a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to start with

Comment: if i replace my jpanel to ; JFrame frame = new JFrame en then replace "jpanel2" to frame , then my code works but then a second frame is opening with the image , but i want to show my image in that jpanel that i named jPanel2 in my first frame

Comment: Diagnosing these problems through comments is pointless and hardly ever works. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 2):

This code works, hope it helps. Probably some more Exceptionhandling, is required.

```
package tests;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tests extends JFrame {

public Tests() {
    super("label Test");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Image image = null;
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.mkyong.com/image/mypic.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Malformed URL");
    } catch (IOException iox) {
        System.out.println("Can not load file");
    }
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tests d = new Tests();
}
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! That said, the url given in your example is broken.